# cannot find implementation for database Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am writing my first application with Room. I discovered it has issues when it uses kotlin, even some sample doesn't work on my machine, so I rollback to plain Java.

```
FilmsDatabaseJ db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), FilmsDatabase.class, "DATABASE_NAME").build();
```

This call fails with exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.home.myapplication.films.storage.FilmsDatabase. FilmsDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

I explored source code, Room expects to have such class already (does generated somewhere?), but by some reason such class doesn't exist for my case which is not far from documentation. Could you please share your ideas what might went wrong here?

```
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
@Database(entities = {Film.class, User.class, UserFilms.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class FilmsDatabaseJ extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATABASE_NAME";

    private static FilmsDatabaseJ instance;

    public abstract FilmsDaoJ getFilmsDao();


    @NotNull
    public static FilmsDatabaseJ getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (FilmsDatabaseJ.class) {
                if (instance != null) return
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, FilmsDatabaseJ.class, DATABASE_NAME).build();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
} 



   annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    // Room (use 1.1.0-beta2 for latest beta)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Did you add the annotation processor to your `dependencies` closure in `build.gradle`? See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Comment: Yes, I did. Just added it to the post

Comment: The error in your title differs from the error in your question. Which of these are you getting? If you are getting the "usable public constructor" one, that would be tied to your `@Entity` classes or any POJOs returned by methods on your `@Dao` class.

Comment: Thank you for catch! It is not correct title. I fixed it

Comment: OK. The annotation processor should be generating the code in `build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/home/myapplication/films/storage/impl/`, inside of your module (e.g., `app/`). Is anything showing up there?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing. Only this build/generated/source/apt/debug

Comment: If there are no other compiler errors before the "cannot find implementation" one, then I can't explain your symptoms. It is as if the annotation processor is failing or not running.

Comment: No, there is not any other errors. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the kotlin compiler doesn't work well with @Database java annotation (which generates the `FilmsDatabase_Impl` for you).

So to fix this:

- First you need to get the `kapt` plugin to parse annotation in kotlin file, add this to your app level gradle:

  `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`
- Then replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt` for the Room's compiler

  `kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"`
- Compiling the project again now you should see those boiler plate codes get generated and resolve the above error.

Comment: Thank you. It was a while when I worked with Room, may be I already found the answer. I don't remember. I'll accept your replay when find time to verify it.

Comment: yeah just in case someone else could stumble in the same issue, hope it might help then

Comment: Four (4) years later and have exact same problem!

Answer (score 0):

solution:
def room_version = "2.3.0"

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
```